# Is a URI path the same as an XPath?

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath, uri

I have an XPath:   `//*[@class='sl-count']`

However, my plugin is requesting for URI path.

Are they the same? Can I just use the XPath for URI path?
Or can I transform XPath into URI path?

Comment: No, they're not the same. What are you trying to do? What's your plugin?

Comment: My guess (with very little information) is that the plugin is asking for the URI of the document that you want to process using this XPath.

Comment: Hi, it's Cloudflare - I want some dynamic information to skip the CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a URI path is not the same as an XPath:

- A [URI](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html) (Universal Resource Identifier) identifies a ***document***.
- An [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Introduction) identifies a ***part*** of a (XML or related) document.

Therefore, no, a tool requesting a URI is not going to accept an XPath in its place, but it might accept an XPath in addition to the URI so that it can first retrieve the document via the URI and then select a part of the document via the XPath.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I find the URI path? (sorry I'm not a techie or a coder...)  Is it possible to search through "Inspect" function in chrome?

Comment: Locate the file using a web browser.  If it's on a remote website, use a search engine or a link within another webpage; the URI will start with `https:`.  If it's on your local computer, use "File→Open..."; the URI start with `file:`.